# Random solute transport equation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, linear-pde, random-functions

After reading the article *Probability density functions for solute transport in random fields*, by  M. Shvidler, K. Karasaki, see  https://pubarchive.lbl.gov/islandora/object/ir%3A116072/datastream/PDF/download/citation.pdf, I have some doubts:

1. In page 5, equation (4), the authors write the density function $p(x,t;c)$ as $\delta(c(x,t)-c)$. I do not understand what this means: $c(x,t)$ is random and $\delta$ evaluated at it should be random.
2. On the other hand, in equations (5) and (6), the right-hand side is random, but the left-hand side is not. I do not understand those two equations.

Comment: the lower case $p$ of section 1 is random, the non-random probability density function is denoted with a capital $P$ and introduced in the next section.